# unbalanced binary tree search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was in a tech interview and one of the interviewers asked me

*What type of search would you use to scan an unbalanced binary tree?*

and I couldn't answer, could someone help me with this answer for future interviews?

Comment: Are you sure that was the question?

Comment: yes, that was the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the interviewer was getting at the important difference in which algorithms are appropriate for traversing balanced vs. unbalanced trees.

When the tree is not known to be balanced, then it becomes inappropriate to traverse it using a recursive DFS, because it can take O(N) stack space.  Stacks are a lot smaller than the heap, and stack space is too precious to waste this way.

For this reason, you would usually use **BFS, or DFS with an explicit stack**, if you want to traverse an unbalanced tree.  You could also use an in-order traversal, again with an explicit stack if the tree doesn't have parent pointers.

Note that the question appears not to make any sense, since traversals and searches are different things, but the answer I gave is about using "searches" to traverse.  If you start with the answer in mind, you could end up asking the question that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the question to make more sense

Comment: There's no need to use an "explicit stack". Just replace recursion with iteration where a node has only a single child.

Comment: @valdo that doesn't work.   If every internal node has 2 children, you can still get to a depth of N/2.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: as long as internal nodes have 2 children, the tree is balanced, and there's no problem to traverse recursively

Comment: @valdo imagine that every right child is a leaf, and every left child is a tree like the root.  Not balanced.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: you are right! I didn't think of this. 10x.